# Grep command with if statement

Tags: bash, scripting, tags, grep

Considering the following log file ,

```
FSDFFDSFFDSFDS VCXVCXVCX 3343022340 IT_ON FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03
DDSDS232323SD DSADFSDA SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
DDSDS232323SD DSADFSDA SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
DDSDSDEERWREF FSFDSDFFDS  SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3Q
DDSDS232323SD DSADFSDA SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADSDA 
DSADSE3QZCD FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDS  IT_ON FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRRT
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_OFF FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRRT
DDSDSDEERWREF FSFDSDFFDS  SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
DDSDS232323SD DSADFSDA SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_ON FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRRT
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_OFF FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRRF
DDSDSDEERWREF FSFDSDFFDS  SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
DDSDS232323SD DSADFSDA SDA32323 SDADSDQ SDAFDSADS SDA DSADSE3QZCD
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_ON FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRRT
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_OFF FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRR
FFDSFDAREDFS 23FDSFDDSFK 3343022340 IT_OFF FDSFR0W3EV VXDF03ETRR
```

i have to count how many transitions IT_ON to IT_OFF and IT_OFF to IT_ON occur, i.e.

```
IT_ON to IT_OFF : 3
IT_OFF to IT_ON : 2
```

I've been trying to use *grep "IT_ON"* and *grep "IT_OFF"* with IF statements but it's a bit complicated.
Any help?

Comment: Define a transition for this use case. Also, how are you determining a transition pair, and what have you tried so far?

Comment: I'm asking how to define a transition IT_ON to IT_OFF and i don't have any idea of what should i do.

Answer (score 1):

```
awk '/IT_ON/ {on = 1; if (off) {on_to_off++}; off = 0} /IT_OFF/ {off = 1; if (on) {off_to_on++}; on = 0} END {print "IT_ON to IT_OFF :", on_to_off; print "IT_OFF to IT_ON :", off_to_on}' inputfile
```

Broken out on multiple lines:

```
awk '
    /IT_ON/ {
        on = 1; 
        if (off) {
            on_to_off++
        }; 
        off = 0
    } 
    /IT_OFF/ {
        off = 1; 
        if (on) {
            off_to_on++
        }; 
        on = 0
    } 
    END {
        print "IT_ON to IT_OFF :", on_to_off; 
        print "IT_OFF to IT_ON :", off_to_on
    }' inputfile
```

If there is an ID that you need to use to track the transitions per ID, then you can use the same technique with an array. Also, you might need to use a flag to set the ON state the first time it's seen to ensure that an initial ON is counted as an off-to-on transition.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another approach:

```
 grep -Po "IT_(ON|OFF)" inputFile \
 | uniq | paste - - \
 | awk 'NR==1 && NF==2{print;f=1}END{if(f)printf "%3d\t%3d\n", NR,NR-1}'
```

Output format:

```
IT_ON   IT_OFF
  3       2
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data file is named `data.log`:

```
grep -Eo 'IT_(ON|OFF)' data.log | uniq | tail -n +2 |sort |uniq -c
```

Output:

```
3 IT_OFF
2 IT_ON
```

Annotated:

```
grep -Eo 'IT_(ON|OFF)' data.log $(: -E for extended regex, -o to only print matching part ) \
  | uniq                        $(: deduplicate adjacent items ) \
  | tail -n +2                  $(: drop the first line )        \
  | sort | uniq -c              $(: sort , then give a count for each unique item )
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what you want however, may work:

```
sed -n 's/.*\(IT_ON\|IT_OFF\).*/\1/p' input | uniq > input.tmp
grep $(head -1 input.tmp) input.tmp | uniq -c
expr $(grep $(head -2 input.tmp | tail -1) input.tmp | wc -l) - 1
rm input.tmp
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a shell script in bash that does what you ask:

```
#!/bin/bash

testfile="test.txt"

uniques=$(command grep -o IT_O. $testfile | uniq)
count=$(echo "$uniques" | paste - - | grep -c "IT_O.[[:space:]]IT_O.")

if [[ ${uniques:0:5} = "IT_ON" ]]; then
    echo "IT_ON  -> IT_OFF: $count"
    echo "IT_OFF -> IT_ON : $(($count-1))"
else
    echo "IT_ON  -> IT_OFF: $(($count-1))"
    echo "IT_OFF -> IT_ON : $count"
fi
```

Unfortunately, I could not spend too much time on testing -- please run a few trials to see if it is robust enough for your use case.

Answer (score 0):

In awk:

```
/IT_ON/        { on=1; }
on && /IT_OFF/ { offs++; on=0; off=1; }
off && /IT_ON/ { ons++; off=0; on=1; }
END {
  printf("ON to OFF: %d\nOFF to ON: %d\n", offs, ons);
}
```

Returns:

```
ON to OFF: 3
OFF to ON: 2
```

You could implement the same logic in any language, including shell, but this seems cleanest to me.